# Solr tokenizer - Match exact words before tokenizing

Tags: solr

I have a requirement that , if i am searching for **'Which are'** the first result of solr should be the text containing **'Which are'** and thereafter it should be like matching either **'Which'** or 'are'. Currently if i search for **'Which are'** , the sentence containing **'Which'** are coming at the top and containing **'Which are'** is way below in search result .

Comment: Could you please paste your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try boosting a document..Use `Query-time boosts`

`Query-time boosts` are applied when constructing a search query, and apply to specific fields.

`Query boosts` are applied by appending the caret character `^` followed by a positive number to query clauses

```
title:"Which are"^10
```

Comment: This will list all entries with "Which are" matching . I still need entries matching either Which or are in the response just below the matching entries with "Which are".

Comment: Yes. As per you query title:"Which are"^10 it will look for exact match .
I need to query as title:*Which are* and sentence containing "Which are" should come on top.

Comment: Cant you add the 'OR' option to it...like title:"Which are"^10 OR title:Which are ...check if this works for you?

Comment: check like this ...title:”Which are”^20 OR title:(Which are)^5...you can trytitle:title:”Which are”^20 OR title:(Which are)^5 OR Which OR are....

Comment: Thanks for letting me about boosting .